# angular get rid of braces in links url

Tags: angular

I have angular application with lazy loading. when i go t link it makes braces around links url how i can fix it? for instance http://localhost:4200/#/unigrants/(countingAssignments)
i need to make http://localhost:4200/#/unigrants/countingAssignments
here is routing  module

```
const routes: Routes = [`enter code here`
  {
    path: "countingAssignments",
    component: CountingTasksPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: "countingDucuments/:taskId",
    component: CountingDucumentsPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: "namedList/:taskId",
    component: NamedListPageComponent
  },{
  path:"transferDocumentArchive",
    component:TransferDocumentArchivePageComponent
  },{
    path:"transferDocuments",
    component:TransferDocumentsPageComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: what does your link look like? <a routerLink="... ?

Comment: <a
              class="dropdown-item"
              routerLink="../countingDucuments/{{ rowData.taskId }}"
              fragment="search"
              [queryParams]="searchFormData"
            >დათვლის დოკუმენტის ნახვა{{ rowData.taskId }}}</a>

Comment: And the link for countingAssignments (as that was the original example)? I noticed you have one extra `}` above at the end of the countingDucuments link text but I don't think that's the issue.That would just show an extra `}` in the link.

Comment: yes that's not an issue something other is happening i'm generating some links dinamicaly ill post when ill find problem thanks for reply